# BlinkMacSystemFont does not allow highlighting text when saving as PDF

Tags: html, css, pdf

I have the following HTML page:

```
<style>
body {font-family: BlinkMacSystemFont;}
</style>
text
```

When viewed in Chrome on OS X 10.11, `text` is displayed in the system font (supposedly San Francisco with El Capitan and Helvetica Neue with Yosemite). When I save the webpage as a PDF and open it in Preview, I cannot select the text and highlight by clicking and dragging, and instead the entire page is selected as if it is an image. I've checked the PDF properties using Adobe Reader and there are no embedded fonts used. How can I fix this to be able to select individual text? Is there any way around this?

Comment: You will need to provide far more context.  Please see [MCVE].

Comment: Sure, could you let me know which areas you lack context? This feels like a weird issue to me and I'm not sure how to clearly phrase it.

Comment: Currently there is no way for anyone here to reproduce this issue (particularly since it involves specific fonts on specific systems). I understand that this is a strange problem, but that doesn't mean that it can be reproduced by the community  If it can't be reproduced, it can't be answered in a meaningful manner.

Comment: Apple Preview is a horrible substitute for a proper PDF reader. Download Adobe Reader and try with that. You can also check if the font is correctly embedded.

Comment: Thanks. After using Adobe Reader and checking the Fonts section in the Document Properties, there are no embedded fonts. Is the issue in how the PDF is created, seeing as a the generic system font was not specifically described in the CSS?

Answer (score 2):

OpenType fonts have a concept of permissable usage. This defines how/if the font can be embedded and used. Some fonts allow the entire font to be embedded and redistributed. Some fonts allow a subset of the glyphcs to be embedded, which is useful when a document only uses a small number of glyphs in a unicode font. Some fonts only allow a rasterized (bitmap) reproduction of the glyph. Some don't allow any embedding. Tools that produce PDFs and the like must follow the rules, or could face legal action from Apple. I certainly wouldn't want to be on the receiveing end of that.

I suspect that the OSX fonts are of the category that only allows rasterized embedding. Your best bet is to find another font that doens't have this restriction.